# Quickly generating Vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create a column vector with 30 same-valued components in MATLAB

Sure I can just write

```
 v = [1;1;1;1;1;1;...;1]
```

with 30 1's, but after reviewing a MATLAB textbook and looking online I haven't found a way that you can simplify this with an expression that denotes how many values you want to be put in of a certain value (like you can do in numpy).

Is there a way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: use the ones function: `ones(30,1)`

Comment: If speed is the goal, you'll probably only wan to use `ones` if you are in fact allocating an array of all ones. If it is something else, like `3`, then `zeros(30,1)+3` will probably be faster. Lots more details [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/allocation-performance-take-2/) and [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way of doing it is

```
v_row = repmat(some_value, 1, count);
```

or

```
v_column = repmat(some_value, count, 1);
```

Where `some_value` is the value you want to initialize your vector with. `count` is the number of values you want to generate.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
v = some_value .* ones(1,count); // Row vector
```

or

```
v = some_value .* ones(count,1); // Column vector
```

Where `some_value` is the value you want to initialize your vector with. `count` is the number of values you want to generate.

Comment: The comment from Dan does what I need to do, but thank you for the generalization. Works perfect!

Comment: @user3239567.. You may accept the answer if it solves the problem. :)

Comment: The question says "quickly" so, `v = some_value + zeros(1,count);` will [probably be faster](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/allocation-performance-take-2/) for everything except maybe `1`.